# SocketTimeOutException (id=830027971416)/cause ErrorException (id=830029535888)

Tags: android, exception, vnc

I am not sure if my question is right...@@

(complete source code: https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server)

I run the source code in the above link on Windows XP, Eclipse AVD(API level 14), and it failed at the step to start the sever.

While I am tracing the code in debug mode, I got an exception on this code

```
public static boolean isServerRunning() {
    try {
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(100);
        String toSend = "~PING|";
        byte[] buffer = toSend.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket question = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,
                addr, 13132);
        clientSocket.send(question);

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String receivedString = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        receivedString = receivedString.substring(0, receivePacket
                .getLength());

        return receivedString.equals("~PONG|");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

when it run to this line "clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);"

it goes to "catch (Exception e)"

The content of variable e is

```
e:                       SocketTimeOutException (id=830027971416)
   bytes Transferred      0
  +cause                  ErrorException (id=830029535888)
   detailMessage          null
  +stackState             (id=830027970928)
   stackTrace             null
  +suppressedExceptions   ArrayList(id=830027971456)
```

---

Now I　know its an exception cause by the sever didn't answer on time．(Thanks for Class Stacker). So I comment this line "clientSocket.setSoTimeout(100);"  to waited a long time and find out it still stuck.

I don't know if there should be some device connected when running the AVD, or it can just run on the AVD only.

I look the variable "clientSocket", it's subcontent "address" got a null and the "port" got a -1 after this line "clientSocket.send(question);". Is this a correct result? (I read the explanation of the class on the android package website, but remain not understand. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html)

Comment: Would e.getMessage() maybe shed some more light on this?

Comment: 100ms timeout is not very much. Where is your server located as compared to your client?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the question. (I am a begginer, try to trace the source code...@@)
This is run by AVD.

Comment: The question is: Are you sure your server answers within 100ms? Because you specified a 100ms timeout. So if you see a timeout exception, it means that the server hasn't answered on time, or that the answer did not reach your Android device. Do you know how to use wireshark?

Comment: I forget to tell the information. This app is run on the cell phone to let the cell phone to be a server and the computer to be the client. But it also has the option to reverse connected, too.
As I run the AVD, so I think the AVD is the server.

Comment: So this is the same app for client and server? With the above code, you test whether the communication with "yourself" works? And you have another thread which deals with the PING?

Comment: Q:So this is the same app for client and server? 
A:Although it has the inverse connection option, I don't try it successfully. This code is for server, the client can connect the server by http. The client does not need to has this app. 

Q:you test whether the communication with "yourself" works? 
A: You mean myself is both the server and the client? No, I stuck on   the step of starting the server. The server can not be start, so I can't do any connection.

Comment: Q:And you have another thread which deals with the PING?
A: I am not sure how to figure out this right now...

Comment: Please edit your Q and supply the following additional information: For the failing test, where does the code above run (device, platform, JAVA class) and where does the server run (device, platform, JAVA class)? Why can't the server be started and what have you tried?

Comment: Really thank you for your patience. :)
I edit the question and  still working for getting more knowledge...

Comment: You don't need a real Android device; the AVD will do. But can you finally describe your setup in more detail please. Do you have _one_ app which implements both client and server (I think yes)? For your test, how many AVDs do you run and whcih AVD runs the server and which runs the client?

Comment: Okay if "this" (the above shown) app is server side, then the code you showed above is a test in the server app to test whether the server is really running? YES/NO? If YES, then are you aware that you need two concurrent Threads for this to succeed, because the same app must answer its own request?

Comment: Sorry for not catch your thought. @@
This app is for server, the client need another app or it can be linked by http.
There is just one AVD, I think the class isServerRunning() should be work at first then it can be connect to a client. So so far, there is just an AVD for server and no AVD for client.

Comment: Do you know what would happen to clientSockt when executed this line : "clientSocket.send(question);" ?

I think the clientSocket.receive(receivePacket) will receive data but it doesn't. (address:null, port:-1)
 is AVD can't work tcp/ip correctly?

Comment: YES. But I don't understand why there should be two threads? Isn't the send task end when the request was thrown out, then it can do the line of receive to wait for the answer?

Comment: There is no _implicit_ threading, only _explicit_ threading. The `send()` call leaves your app for a moment, entering the operating system, where no blocking occurs, so the system returns to your thread of code, finally coming across `receive()`, which invokes the operating system again. Now `receive()` blocks and the operating system (or Java scheduler if you will) looks for other things to do. _If_ your _server code_ were running in a separate thread, this would be where it would be figured that you server code's `receive()` now has something to do. Buit that's not the case here.

Comment: I suggest you read about multithreading background first and study some example code.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much, really appreciated your kindness :)

Comment: sorry for not having enough reputation to vote @@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, you're not creating a separate Thread for this test. This "fake client" code runs in the server app, in the same Thread which should serve the PING request and provide the PONG response.

One quick solution would be to wrap this code inside a `Runnable` and start a separate `Thread` for it. A quick start example would be (throwing away the result for now,

```
# start your concurrent request on-the-fly
Thread serverTest = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { isServerRunning(); }});
serverTest.start();
```

But please study the details about concurrency, `synchronized`, `volatile` and using `HandlerThread` and `AsyncTask` rather than `Thread` on Android.